# Are there any resources, gem, plugging, to aid implementing @mentions on a native comments implementation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments

I want to let people address each other via @username on a regular comment form much how disqus and twitter works.

I am using rails.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mentions 
Take a look at this, i think jquery plugin is what are you looking for.